# Can I connect to SharePoint server from visual studio running locally?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to connect to share point server and access its list and libraries from visual studio on my local desc is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by CSOM or rest calls.

You can also setup a S2S trust in order to use app permissions.

Have a start here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code

edit: More detailed question for a more detailed answer ;)